# If I have two await Task.Run()'s in a method will the second wait for the first to complete?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

In my `OnStart` I need to run code that gets data and then runs a `CheckScore` method. `GetData` must have completed before `CheckScore` runs.  Also is this the correct way to be calling a method? Neither `Method()` or `CheckScore()` run asynchronously.

Can someone tell me if there is a difference between doing it like this:

```
protected override async void OnStart()
{
    await Task.Run(() => Method());
}

public void Method() 
{
    App.DB.GetData();
    PointChecker.CheckScore();
}
```

or like this:

```
protected override async void OnStart()
{
    await Task.Run(() => Method());
    await Task.Run(() => PointChecker.CheckScore());
}

public void Method() 
{
    App.DB.GetData();
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind, `await` is "pause this method if whetever is to it's right is not yet completed". If you think it does something else, you're probably mistaken.

Comment: @Fildor - `async` is never part of the *signature*. It's an implementation detail of the method that happens to appear in an odd place that makes it look like it might be part of the signature. It's why interfaces cannot mark methods as `async` and there's no need for a match up between virtual/override methods.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Of course, you are right. What I meant to say was "just because 'async' keyword is used here" ...

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you mean Damien.  Is the first or second solution okay?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve Alan? If you want those methods to execute sequentially, then you should just call `Method(); PointChecker.CheckScore();` without all of the Task/await stuff.

Comment: I was thinking that using Await would allow the OnStart() to finish so that the UI could update. Maybe that thinking was wrong.  Can you comment on that for me?

Comment: You can call any number of methods from a single method that has been launched from `Task.Run()` without it stopping the UI from responding. It only become synchronous if you access the return value from the task *without* `await`, or call `Task.Wait()`.

Comment: @Alan2 if these methods don't need to be completed for UI to be ready, you can just fire and forget. i.e. call `Task.Run` without await.

Comment: @SelmanGenç But spare a second to think about exception handling if you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will the second wait for the first to complete?

Yes. Any code below the first await:

```
await Task.Run(() => Method());
```

will **wait** until the execution has finshed.

> Can someone tell me if there is a difference...

In your simplified example there is basically **no** difference. You have an `async` method which runs internally synchronous and sequential.

If you want any other work to be done in the meanwhile you can set the await a little later:

```
protected override async void OnStart()
{
    Task methodTask = Task.Run(() => Method());

    // do anything here while the Task runs

    await methodTask; // wait here so that CheckScore() is not started yet

    await Task.Run(() => PointChecker.CheckScore());
}
```

> I was thinking that using Await would allow the OnStart() to finish so that the UI could update.

since you have declared `OnStart` as `async´ it will not block the UI, which will stay responsive. Since you have no return values and no update code in your example. This is as far my answer can go without assuming too much.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they will be run after each other. The point of await async pattern is, to not block the thread until the method has completed. The OS will manage to get the status of the task. As soon as it completed, it will continue. In the meantime, while it is executed, and perhaps waiting for an I/O or whatever to perform, it will allow other tasks to use the CPU resources.